# preview image after upload

Tags: javascript, php

I have a image upload page. When user upload an image they can preview it and add text into it before it save into database.

my question is

how can i preview the image in 2nd (preview page)

1.I have try file reader, but its not work for most of old browser. so im seeking another way

2.do i need to create another folder and save temp image into it?
(than save it into image folder after user have finished the editing)

something like google+ or facebook, how did they achieve this?

Comment: Please show your code and explain what you've tried.

Comment: Take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: `<input type = "file">` would be the easiest way to do it for HTML5. You will need to make a separate app that can handle file uploading (in Java or Flash for example) for non-HTML5 browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just receive the uploaded file, save it into some temporary folder and then show back to client. If they save form then move into the final folder. Otherwise every 24 hrs (or whatever you feel is necessary) delete the image or maybe if you can track pages then delete old images when they change pages